# How to convert object column to geometry in pandas python?

Tags: python, pandas, type-conversion, geospatial

I have a dataframe that includes these three columns:

```
lat         long            Mapped Location

36.0455         -86.7122    POINT (-86.7122 36.0455)
36.1343         -86.7806    POINT (-86.7806 36.1343)
36.1208         -86.8029    POINT (-86.8029 36.1208)
```

I want to create a geodataframe using the Mapped Location points but the column's datatype of is object. I'm able to create a new geometry column using the lat and long columns, but that seems like a waste since I already have that info.

I tried:

```
df['Mapped Location'] = df['Mapped Location'].astype(str)
df['Mapped Location'] = df['Mapped Location'].apply(wkt.loads)
```

I got this error:

> Expected word but encountered number: 'nan'

Comment: I see people posting how you would go about it using geopandas but did any of those actually solve your issue of encountering a Nan value when processing your geometries? Also do you want to keep it in pandas or is geopandas fine?

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement/desired output is not clear. But here is an attempt to solve your problem.

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely import wkt

data = {
    'lat': [36.0455, 36.1343, 36.1208],
    'long': [-86.7122, -86.7806, -86.8029],
    'Mapped Location': ['POINT (-86.7122 36.0455)', 'POINT (-86.7806 36.1343)', 'POINT (-86.8029 36.1208)'],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.dropna(subset=['Mapped Location'], inplace=True)
df['Mapped Location'] = df['Mapped Location'].apply(wkt.loads)
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry='Mapped Location')
print(gdf)
```